# HttpActionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri returns url with port number only on production?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

When i log `HttpActionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri`, it returns: 
http://productionurl.com:8083/api/stocks/1/images/

I have no clue how this port number :8083 is getting appended.

Issue it causes is that i am hashing document with url as http://productionurl.com/api/stocks/1/images/ [Same url without port number] and hence hash match fails on production.

How can i find how this port number gets appended and how can i avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

It is related to how you configured your website on production. It looks like that your website is configured using port 8083 on production. Default HTTP port is 80 which means if no port is specified then it is 80.

URL - `http://productionurl.com/api/stocks/1/images/`  is same as `http://productionurl.com:80/api/stocks/1/images/`

Just double check in IIS website settings. The port should be 80 if you don't want it to append in URL.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because in your local your website must be running on 8080(which is default) and on your production its running on a different port which is not default.